# Clear and Reload PDF with axAcroPDF

Tags: c#, axacropdf

I have a axAcroPDF object with a textbox and two buttons.

Button1 loads Open File Dialog, sends a filename/path to the axAcroPDF object and sends the filename/path to a textbox.

What I want with button3 is to realase the loaded pdf file and clear the filename from the textbox. So that the user can reload another pdf file.

My attempt is below:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
            axAcroPDF1.Dispose();
            axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");
            axAcroPDF1.Show();
        }
```

Initially, I've tried with `axAcroPDF1.Hide();` and `axAcroPDF1.Dispose();`

This hides the axAcroPDF, but I'm unable to reload a new file.

Any suggestions how I should fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearing the AxAcroPDF is as simple as providing a file, that doesn't exist:

```
AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile("Empty")
```

A lot of people are confused the same way, trying to achive this...